# Java HTTPResponse returning null

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to read an API response using a GET request. The URL is a string that is created in another class and is passed. I have validated that the URLs that are being created are valid and working but my return value is null. The odd thing about this is that it works once correctly when I make another call, but every other time it's called after the first, it only returns null.

Here is an example API call that I am passing my function:

https://api.smmry.com/?SM_API_KEY=key&SM_URL=https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/variety/long-way-before-ai-systems-take-over-humans-jobs-study/article25938621.ece

I have tested this and it returns what I am expecting in the browser. Here is the code that is returning null:

```
public String getResponse(String url)  {
        HttpClient client = null;
        String line = "";
        try {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request;
            request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            //Check if the response code is not 200
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                Logger.error(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                return "Error";
            }
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
              while (rd.readLine() != null) {
                  line = line + rd.readLine();
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e);
        } 
        return line;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (rd.readLine() != null) {
    line = line + rd.readLine();
}
```

By doing that you are skipping one line of two. The most common usage of `BufferedReader` is :

```
String line = null;
while ( (line = reader.readLine())!=null ) {
    buffer += line;
}
// buffer contains the whole text
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that for each iteration of the loop two lines from `rd` are being read. At the beginning of the loop `while (rd.readLine() != null)` the method `readLine()` returns the current line in `rd` and sets the iterator marker at the next line. Then when `readLine()` is called the second time, `rd` returns the next line and concatenates it with the value of `line`. Since the response to your request has only one line the second call to `readLine()` returns `null`, the loop brakes and the line is returned with the value `null`.

You should store the value returned in the first call to `readLine()` and use `StringBuilder` to concatenate.

```
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            responseBody = builder.toString();
   .
   .
   .
return responseBody;
```